# android picture frame

Tags: android

I'm new to android i'm developing small application i want to arrange pictures in screen just like tumbnail view and want scroll on all picture then i have to able to select the one picture after touching the picture on the screen how can i do it? plz help me

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you have to rephrase your question. It is very hard to understand. And very general you should try to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do that using a Gallery control to scroll the thumbnails, then when you select the picture (using the method gallery.setOnItemClickListener()) that image will be showed in the ImageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >   
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />        
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="320px" 
        android:layout_height="250px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```